# Does BERT model and tokenizer should be trained with same data?

Tags: bert-language-model

I want to make BERT model by training with more data (not a fine-tuning, the base model which will be trained is 'bert-base-uncased'). However, do i always need to create own tokenizer for one model? when i use 'bert-base-uncased' tokenizer to train model, it give me some error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(model(**input_idx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py", line 989, in forward
    embedding_output = self.embeddings(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py", line 214, in forward
    inputs_embeds = self.word_embeddings(input_ids)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py", line 158, in forward
    return F.embedding(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2044, in embedding
    return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
IndexError: index out of range in self
```

so does the model should have it's own tokenizer which trained with same data?

Comment: You can reuse the tokenizer from any pre-trained model. But keep in mind that is better to actually have a tokenizer for the specific corpus you are going to use to train it. Nevertheless, the error that you show is probably due to the size of the embedding matrix is different (smaller) than the size of the tokenizer.

Comment: Okay i got it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to actually resize the embeedding matrix to match the size of the tokenizer you want to use:

```py
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
```

Huggingface docs: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/master/en/main_classes/model#transformers.PreTrainedModel.resize_token_embeddings